# How to check if a product is a simple product

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I know how to check if a product is configurable or not. I also got how to check if a simple product is a child of a configurable product or not. But can anyone tell me how to check if a product is a pure simple product?

That means that I want to check those products which I created as `Attribute set='Default'` and `Product type='Simple Product'` not `attribute set='Default'` and `Product type='configurable Product'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();

$parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());

if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && empty($parentIds) && $attributeSetName == 'Default') {
    echo "This is a simple product with no parent configurable product in the 'Default' attribute set";
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Spars. I also developed the same logic in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope ,you want `simple collection filter with default attribute`  which are `not in configurable products  child Simple Product`.

Then first get Default attribute set id

```
 $entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getEntityType();
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType->getId());
$collection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name','Default');
$attrbuteSetId= $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

After that filter Product `Collection with simple product type and of non default  Attribute set`.

```
$productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array('nin'=>$attrbuteSetId));
```

Then fetch `Simple product ids` `which are used in Configurable product`.

```
$select = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
        ->select()
        ->from('catalog_product_super_link', array('product_id'))
        ->group('product_id');
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($select);
```

now final collection

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('nin'=>$results));
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question I don't want child of configurable products or a configurable product. I just want simple product with default attribute set

Comment: are you want simple Products with default attribute set of a   configurable Product???

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ): ?>
//your code for simple products 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @Karlis: yeah its returns simple product but this code also returns the child product of a configurable product.

Comment: @Poles Try compare my and amit Bera answers. Take my answer in first if block, then put second if block ($childId=12;//simple Product id;
 $ConfigProduct=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
if(!empty($ConfigProduct)){
 // childId is simple product of Configuration 
})